# Como enviar o resultado de uma consulta por e-mail SHELL SCRIPT

Tags: mysql, shell-script

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
#!/bin/bash
db="bats";
table="promotion";
dbHost="192.168.0.246";
dbUser="root";
dbPass="root";
result=`mysql -h $dbHost --user=$dbUser --password=$dbPass --skip-column-names -e "SELECT name FROM  $db.$table WHERE finish > now() ORDER BY promotion_key DESC"`

campanha=$(echo $result | tr " " "\n")


   echo "$campanhas"
```

Quero pegar esse resultado e enviar por e-mail,como faria essa função ?

Tentei isso também:

```
sendmail -s "CAMPANHAS" suporte@email.com.br < $campanha
```

Mais deu o seguinte erro:

```
./query.sh: line 14: $campanha: ambiguous redirect
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `sendmail` é uma boa alternativa, mas eu normalmente uso o `mail` mesmo, no BASH, por já vir em uma série de *distros* e estar pronto pra usar.

De qualquer forma, para envio básico, a sintaxe é parecida, e tanto o `mail` quanto o `sendmail` podem ser usados conforme os exemplos abaixo.

Exemplo com arquivo:

```
cat conteudo.html | mail -s "Assunto" contato@spam.com
```

Exemplo com variável:

```
echo $variavel | mail -s "Assunto" contato@spam.com
```

Aplicado ao seu caso:

```
mysql -h ... etc "... BY promotion_key DESC" | mail -s "CAMPANHAS" suporte@email.com.br
```

Se precisar, tem flags para anexos, e outras coisinhas interessantes, veja os manuais:

- **`mail`**        http://linux.die.net/man/1/mail
- **`sendmail`** http://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $campanha | sendmail -s "CAMPANHAS" suporte@bigmais.com.br
```